# Web Audio API: How do I play a mono source in only left or right channel?

Tags: web-audio-api

Is there an (easy) way to take a mono input and play it only in the left or right channel? I'm thinking I can do it through the ScriptProcessing node, but if there is a node meant to handle this situation I'd really like to know. The API has a section on mixing, but I don't see any code on how to manipulate channels yourself in this fashion.

Note, I have tried the panner node, but it doesn't seem to really cut off the left the from the right channel, I don't want any sound bleeding from one channel to the other.

Answer (score 3):

You do want to use the ChannelSplitter, although there is a bug when a channel is simply not connected.  See this issue: [Play an Oscillation In a Single Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464693/play-an-oscillation-in-a-single-channel/14470515#comment20230745_14470515).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the splitter node: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#ChannelSplitterNode-section

> One application for ChannelSplitterNode is for doing "matrix mixing" where individual gain control of each channel is desired.

(I haven't yet tried it, let me know : )

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `CreatePanner()` and then `setPosition()` to the desired channel. Don't forget to connect your previous node to the panner node and the panner to the `context.destination`.

For example:

```
//Lets create a simple oscilator just to have some audio in our context
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();

//Now lets create the panner node
var pannerNode = context.createPanner();

//Connecting the nodes
oscillator.connect(pannerNode); //Connecting the oscillator output to the panner input
pannerNode.connect(context.destination); //Connecting the panner output to our sound output

//Setting the position of the sound
pannerNode.setPosition(-1, 0, 0);//If you want it to play on the left channel
pannerNode.setPosition(1, 0, 0);//If you want it to play on the right channel

//Playing the sound
oscillator.noteOn(0);
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Someone has suggested and edit. Can you review, it looks to have missed a typo at least.