# Web Audio API Panner Node - how do I cut of sound on 100% pan?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-panning

I am looking at the web audio API spec and I use the panner node. It uses three values to create a 3D spectrum for sound.

When I pan 100% Left, I can still hear some sound on the right side(and vice-versa. Can anyone help with settings so that panning 100% to one side completely mutes the other ?

this article suggests that that maybe the panner does not fully cut of the left from the right:
[Web Audio API: How do I play a mono source in only left or right channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623947/web-audio-api-how-do-i-play-a-mono-source-in-only-left-or-right-channel)

I have been experimenting with these settings - but so far none of the combinations I have tried fully mute left/right on 100% pan.

panningModel
distanceModel
rolloffFactor

Is it possible using the Panner Node to fully cut off the sound when panning 100%?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the panner cannot do this so this is on the way
There's a StereoPannerNode on the way:
[link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/%22intent$20to%22/blink-dev/IVDmh6ubHZM/kuG5l8AqWqkJ)

Comment: Indeed. The current models of panning, HRTF or equalpower are more spatialisation techniques rather than panning techniques. Which in turn implies that some sound from a source to the left of your left ear will also reach your right ear and vice versa. Like user3350887 said, you bet is to wait for StereoPannerNode or write your own in ScriptProcessorNode.